# Integrating twice gives a different result than a double integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I would like to compute the following double integral:
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{0}\int_{-v}^{1+v} \frac{2}{1-(u^2-v^2)} dudv = \frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$
When I do this using using

```
Integrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}]
```

> ```
> π^2/12
> ```

the result is $\pi^2/12$ as expected (It took me a while to figure out the strange convention that the first argument to `Integrate` is the outer variable).

However when I try to do the calculation in two steps like

```
Integrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {u, -v, 1 + v}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> ```
> -((2 (ArcTan[v/Sqrt[-1 - v^2]] + ArcTan[(1 + v)/Sqrt[-1 - v^2]]))/Sqrt[-1 - v^2])
> ```

```
Integrate[ %, {v, -1/2, 0}]
```

> ```
> 1/12 (π^2 + 3 ArcCosh[7/2] ArcCsch[2] - 12 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[5]]^2)
> ```

the result is different (I added `GenerateConditions -> False` just for speed, it doesn't seem to change the result).

Why is that? What do I have to do to get the same result for the integration also in two steps?

Comment: Sometimes you can't - the double integral is sometimes not the same as the iterated integral ( or you cannot change the order ) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini's_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions

Comment: All that is not so simple. You deal with an improper double integral as `Plot3D[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 200}]` shows (The integrand is unbounded at $u=1, v=0$.).

Comment: The result of `NIntegrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v},   Exclusions -> {u == 1, v == 0}] `suggests that the improper integral converges though this is not a proof.

Comment: @user64494  Have you doubts anymore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add **assumptions on `v`** or **simplify the result** of the first integral with **appropriate assumptions**.

```
Integrate[ Integrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
           Assumptions -> -1/2 <= v <= 0], {v, -1/2, 0}]
```

> ```
>  Pi^2/12
> ```

Originally the first integral yields the result in terms of `ArcTan`, however with assumptions we get slightly different expression which after another integration **avoids possible issues with terms hard to simplify**.

```
Refine[ Integrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {u, -v, 1 + v}, Assumptions -> -1/2 <= v <= 0], 
        -1/2 < v < 0]
```

> ```
>   (2 (ArcSinh[v] + ArcTanh[(1 + v)/Sqrt[1 + v^2]]))/Sqrt[1 + v^2]
> ```

alternatively we can get it with

```
FullSimplify[ -((2(ArcTan[v/Sqrt[-1 - v^2]] 
              + ArcTan[(1 + v)/Sqrt[-1 - v^2]]))/Sqrt[-1 - v^2]), -1/2 <= v < 0]
```

**Edit**

In the comments there have appeared some doubts whether the integral converges since the integrand diverges as $v \to 0$. To demonstrate the convergence we can follow along standard mathematical techniques or exploit appropriate *Mathematica* functionality.  We are going to make use of the newest functions. The first integral yields
$$
\int_{-1/2}^{0}\int_{-v}^{1+v} \frac{2}{1-(u^2-v^2)} dudv = \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^0\frac{2\left(\operatorname{arcsh}(v)+\operatorname{arcth}(\frac{1+v}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}) \right)}{\sqrt{1+v^2}} dv
$$
The first term in the integral is not harmful and so we take a closer look at the second one. Now we can show

```
Asymptotic[2 ArcTanh[(1 + v)/Sqrt[1 + v^2]]/Sqrt[1 + v^2], v -> 0]
```

> ```
> -Log[v]
> ```

and integrating it with respect to $v$ we can see that the integral converges as the upper integration limit approaches to $0$ from below. Moreover

```
AsymptoticLessEqual[(2 (ArcTanh[(1 + v)/Sqrt[1 + v^2]]))/Sqrt[1 + v^2],-Log[-v],
                     v -> 0, Direction -> +1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

This means that we can find a constant $c$ such that
$\frac{2\operatorname{arcth}(\frac{1+v}{\sqrt{1+v^2}}) }{\sqrt{1+v^2}} \leq c \log(-v)$ for any $v<0$, taking e.g. $c=2$ we can see

```
Plot[{(2 (ArcTanh[(1 + v)/Sqrt[1 + v^2]]))/Sqrt[1 + v^2], -2 Log[-v]},
      {v, -1/2, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

These arguments clarify that the integral actually exists. One can also calculate this integral

```
res = Integrate[(2 (ArcTanh[(1 + v)/Sqrt[1 + v^2]]))/Sqrt[1 + v^2], {v, -1/2, z}, 
           Assumptions -> -1/2 < z < 0]
```

and then calculate the limit

```
Limit[ res, z -> 0, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
```

We have proved, that *Mathematica* correctly deals with this type of the integrand.

Comment: All that is not so simple. You deal with an improper double integral as `Plot3D[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 200}]` shows (The integrand is unbounded at $u=1, v=0$.).

Comment: @user64494 It doesn't matter.

Comment: Artes, could you kindly ground you statement? TIA.

Comment: Artes,the result of `NIntegrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 Exclusions -> {u == 1, v == 0}]` suggests that the improper integral converges though this is not a proof.

Comment: @user64494  You can see the proof of the convergence in the edit of my answer.

Comment: I think the existence of the integral is pretty clear in the polar coordinates `{u -> 1 + r Cos[t], v -> r Sin[t]}` (if you include the jacobian factor).

Comment: @MichaelE2  Right, here my goal was to enlighten the newest functions like `Asymptotic` etc.

Comment: My goal was more mundane, which was to suggest that the means of answering the question of convergence was easily within the reach of @user64494.  I might add further that `Integrate` carried out an internal “proof” of convergence, and before demanding proof from others, one ought to provide grounds for doubting the result. I apologize for the noise on your comment thread.

Comment: @user64494  **Your attitude is impolite**. First you make a statement that something is wrong, then you demand a specific improvement of the answer and when I provide an edit then you don't bother anymore whether that grain of salt has been well-grounded.  I don't expect much however I wouldn't like encountering anyone littering up MSE.  This site is getting up overloaded with too much nonsense stuff and it is reasonable to expect from a long-term user higher standards, isn't it?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No problem, I find your comment legitimate and justified by practical reasons

Answer (score 4):

The results are the same, as

```
3 ArcCosh[7/2] ArcCsch[2]-12 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[5]]^2
```

is actually zero. Mathematica does not seem to realize that, even with `FullSimplify`, but you can check it numerically up to a high number of digits

```
N[1+3 ArcCosh[7/2] ArcCsch[2]-12 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[5]]^2,200]
```

> ```
> 1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
> 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> ```

Comment: All that is not so simple. You deal with an improper double integral as `Plot3D[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 200}]` shows (The integrand is unbounded at $u=1, v=0$.).

Comment: The result of `NIntegrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 Exclusions -> {u == 1, v == 0}]` suggests that the improper integral converges though this is not a proof.

Comment: @Hausdorff Would you say it is a bug in Mathematica that it cannot simplify this expression?

Comment: No, it is generally very hard to determine whether something is truly zero. Mathematica just does not seem to know any transformations that would make everything cancel cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

`PossibleZeroQ` will numerically check for zero if standard transformations do not work.  It, being numerical, is not foolproof, and so it is not a complete rigorous method.  For that reason, @Artes' method is superior in this case.

```
Simplify[
 1/12 (π^2 + 3 ArcCosh[7/2] ArcCsch[2] - 
    12 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[5]]^2),
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. _?PossibleZeroQ :> 0 &}]
```

> ```
> `Simplify::ztest1`: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity `-3 (-Log[1+Times[<<2>>]]+Log[1+1/Sqrt[5]])^2+3 Log[1/2+Sqrt[5]/2] Log[7/2+(3 Sqrt[5])/2]` is equal to zero. Assuming it is.
> ```

```
(*  π^2/12  *)
```

`Simplify` caches results, so the message only appears on first execution.

Comment: All that is not so simple. You deal with an improper double integral as `Plot3D[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 200}]` shows (The integrand is unbounded at $u=1, v=0$.).

Comment: @user64494 Your remark makes no sense. I do not deal with an integral at all.  Unless you mean my approval of Artes' answer.

Comment: Disagreed. `1/12 (π^2 + 3 ArcCosh[7/2] ArcCsch[2] - 
    12 ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[5]]^2)` is a supposed value for the double integral. It is not obvious whether the integral exists and that result is right.  Of course, your transformation leads to `Pi^2/12`.

Comment: @user64494 Then prove whether the integral does or does not exist.

Comment: Michael E2, the result of `NIntegrate[2/(1 - (u^2 - v^2)), {v, -1/2, 0}, {u, -v, 1 + v}, 
 Exclusions -> {u == 1, v == 0}]` suggests that the improper integral converges though this is not a proof.